# Filter item in array - Adding elements in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, methods

I'm beginner in JavaScript and I need to:

I have an array like the one below:

```
[
  {
    name: "Petter",
    totalHour: 14
  }
  {
    name: "Klaus",
    totalHour: 13
  }
  {
    name: "Petter",
    totalHour: 4
  }
  {
    name: "Petter",
    totalHour: 9
  }
  {
    name: "Trevor",
    totalHour: 8
  }
]
```

After iterate in the array, I want to have:

```
[
  {
    name: "Petter",
    totalHour: 27
  }
  {
    name: "Klaus",
    totalHour: 13
  }
  {
    name: "Trevor",
    totalHour: 8
  }
]
```

That is, I want to group the same names and add the respective totalHour.

Is there some method in JavaScript where I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this code helping you

```
var arr = [
  {
    name: "Petter",
    totalHour: 14
  },
  {
    name: "Klaus",
    totalHour: 13
  },
  {
    name: "Petter",
    totalHour: 4
  },
  {
    name: "Petter",
    totalHour: 9
  },
  {
    name: "Trevor",
    totalHour: 8
  }
]

var helper = {};
var result = arr.reduce(function(r, o) {
  var key = o.name;
  
  if(!helper[key]) {
    helper[key] = Object.assign({}, o); // create a copy of o
    r.push(helper[key]);
  } else {
    helper[key].totalHour += o.totalHour;
  }

  return r;
}, []);
```

Comment: Your example worked in the generic example who I showed you, but in my context, it didn't work. Instead of show me the added value, it shows me my Array again and in totalHour is showing "NaN" (not a number), in spite of I have sure is a number, cause when I'm creating this value in my backend, I'm creating like: totalHour: { type: Number, default: 0}. Therefore, I'm so grateful by your help. I'm gonna try to improve my code with your help.